# Game saves on emulators

Tags: pc, emulation, super-mario-bros-3

Is there a way for me to save my game when emulating on my PC. I am using nesterj and I'm emulating super Mario bros 3 from the GBA

Comment: It depends what emulator you are using, but any good emulator should support the game saving.

Comment: @SaintWacko Okay thanks you, I will check if there is an option.

Answer (score 4):

Most emulators also have a 'save state' function, that works outside of the game itself. It basically takes a snapshot of the game at that moment and you can load that directly, instead of starting the game and loading a Rom save.

Comment: If this is the answer to your question, don't forget to mark it as such once you can. :)